# Typescript number or numeric enum type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create a function like this:

```
function test_func(arg1: number: NumericEnum) {
    return number / 2 + 5;
}
```

where arg1 can either be a numeric value or an enum value defined to an integer like this:

```
enum Num {
   x = 1;
   y = 2;
}
```

so that the function could either be `test_func(1)` or `test_func(Num.x)`

Is there a way to define a type like this for the type definition of arg1?

Comment: At least to be syntactically correct signature, you need to change it to `test_func(arg1: number | Num)`

Comment: `function test_func(arg1: number) { return arg1 / 2 + 5; }`  The enum values are already `number` so this is enough: https://tsplay.dev/WKkkMW

Answer (score 1):

The values of a numeric enum like `Num` are already `number` so you don't need to do anything special to include them.  We can say that our function takes any `number`.  `Num.x` is just a property accessor that resolves to the numeric literal `1` so it is fine to call this function with `Num.x`.

```
function test_func(arg1: number) {
    return arg1 / 2 + 5;
}

enum Num {
   x = 1,
   y = 2,
}

test_func(1)
test_func(Num.x)
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/WKkkMW)

A few changes:

- enums use commas `,` instead of semicolons `;`
- the variable in `test_func` is `arg1` rather than `number`.  `number` is the type.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write enum this way.

```
enum NumericEnum {
   x = 1,
   y = 2
}
```

Now, the function below can receive a number or Enum as the argument.

```
test_func(arg1: number | NumericEnum) {
    return arg1 / 2 + 5;
}
```

Check my implementation at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jztbzq?file=src/app/app.component.ts).